# i have JSON data as follows, then i want to display originalName in my table with laravel, how to do it?

Tags: arrays, json, laravel-6

```
{
    "s": true,
    "d": [
        {
            "detailItemImage": []
        },
        {
            "detailItemImage": []
        },
        {
            "detailItemImage": [
                {
                    "originalName": "puma_one.jpg",
                    "itemId": 101,
                    "path": null,
                    "rotate": 0,
                    "fileName": "/accurate/files/data_456811/item-image/item_101/item-image_9d07992d-663a-40d8-ba69-76e3aea874b2.jpg",
                    "extension": ".jpg",
                    "optLock": 0,
                    "thumbnailPath": "/accurate/files/data_456811/item-image/item_101/item-image-thumb_9d07992d-663a-40d8-ba69-76e3aea874b2.jpg",
                    "name": "img0",
                    "id": 50,
                    "seq": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "detailItemImage": []
        }
    ],
    "sp": {
        "page": 1,
        "sort": null,
        "pageSize": 20,
        "pageCount": 1,
        "rowCount": 4,
        "start": 0,
        "limit": null
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. What have you tried so far, where do you fail? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i get error like this "Illegal string offset 'detailItemImage' "

Answer (score -1):

I have code like this, where is the error?

```
<tbody>
                                    @php
                                    $i = 1;
                                    @endphp

                                    @foreach ($data['d'] as $key => $item)

                                    <tr class="odd">
                                        <td>{{ $i++ }}</td>
                                        @foreach ($data['d'['detailItemImage']] as $items)
                                        <td>{{ $items['originalName']}}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="btn-group">
                                                <a href="{{ url('detail-produk/'.$key)}}"
                                                    class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Detail</a>
                                                <a href="" {{--"{{ url('edit-kat/'.$key)}}" --}}
                                                    class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Edit</a>
                                                <a href="" {{--"{{ url('edit-kat/'.$key)}}" --}}
                                                    class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Hapus</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
```

Comment: This is _not_ an answer. Please edit your question and post relevant information there. Thanks

Comment: You can use `edit` button under your post and add the code there. This is `answers` section and it should contain only answers